# "Error: no suitable peers available to initiize from" when querying the blockchain

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've been working with the IBM Blockchain v2 beta for the past few months. About 2 weeks ago (with the platform's update to 1.4.1), I've been getting this error:

"Error processing transaction. Error: no suitable peers available to initialize from"

I have attempted to clear and start a new network, using the same configuration as before. But I am still getting this error.

Connection profile:

```
{
    "name": "mychannel",
    "description": "Network on IBP v2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "org1msp"
    },
    "organizations": {
        "org1msp": {
            "mspid": "org1msp",
            "peers": [
                "173.193.78.236:32758"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "173.193.78.236:32153"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "173.193.78.236:30360": {
            "url": "grpcs://173.193.78.236:30360",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nGIkmI2zmPvspkui+feBwMdBAl8H+Qeb1VsLZMQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "173.193.79.236:32758": {
            "url": "grpcs://173.193.79.236:32758",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nQLIZo/iz1fXBVCl72QUxlStHRXY/\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "173.193.78.236"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "173.193.78.236:32153": {
            "url": "https://173.193.78.236:32153",
            "caName": "ca",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nl1vKEo4aiETiXS9sig==\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\r\n"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With today's GA release, I started a new network and configured it as normal. However, I'm still experiencing the error.

Any possible reasons for this error?

Comment: What does your connection profile look like ? The error indicates that there is no peer defined in it for the organisation defined in the client section.

Comment: @david_k I've updated the OP with the connection profile (with the IPs slightly changed). There is a peer but perhaps in the wrong place?

Comment: difficult to say without seeing the connection profile, but it sounds like it cannot find any appropriate peers in the connection profile to use, so there could be a peer defined but for example it isn't associated with the correct organisation.

Comment: @david_k I found the issue. In my Node.js application, I had set the MSP to 'Org1MSP' when it should have been 'org1msp'.

Comment: Looks like the code was changed in node-sdk 1.4.1, it now defaults to using the mspid of the identity defined at gateway connect time rather than using the entry in the connection profile.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I've two organizations. Using the first organization's connection profile I could interact with the blockchain. But using the second one the above error is found.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [node sdk](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/module-fabric-network.Gateway.html#~DiscoveryOptions). In order connect to the Gateway with a connection profile (gateway.connect) in DiscoveryOptions. You may add gateway option like this.:

```
discovery: {
  "enabled": true,
  "asLocalhost": false }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to share how my problem solved with above posts.The problem was `orgMSPID` was pointing to `org1` hence i did a corrections to address my MSPID in server/utils.js  as mention above.

`var identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());`

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue, and the problem was the connection profile.
You need to add channel configuration before "organizations".

Here is an example.

```
"channels": {
    "mychannel": {
        "orderers":  [
            "orderer.example.com"
        ],
        "peers":{
            "peer0.org1.example.com": []
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate on this? I have the exact same problem, but whas goes into ``peer0.org1.example.com`` array? Moreover, is this supposed to be the name or the url of the peer?

Answer (score 0):

This error looks like it is a result of not configuring anchor peers. You need to configure anchor peers in order to use service discovery to get the full list of peers needed to endorse the transaction. The connection profile just has your own organizations peers.

On IBP, you can configure anchor peers on the channels panel.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue occurred but was finally resolved by correcting the profile file path.

The channels section is not required if discovery is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to share how I solved my problem. The problem was that when I require connection profile file, it was getting cached and new added channels were not present and it was giving me the error. Anyone who has a similar error, please check ur connection profile while gateway is connecting to the network.

```
const networkPath = hfc.getConfigSetting('network-file-path');
delete require.cache[networkPath];
const connectionProfile = require(networkPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and it was all my fault. i created a credential with organization MSP that doesn't exist.

```
    const identityLabel = 'User1@org1.bionic.com';
    const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1', cert, key);

   await wallet.import(identityLabel, identity);
```

here there was no Org1 MSP address but Org1MSP. after fixing that it worked so check what your credential MSP is. hopefully i'll save someones precious time because i've spent almost 2 days with this problem and no solution on the internet for HL

```
    const identityLabel = 'User1@org1.bionic.com';
    const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', cert, key);
    await wallet.import(identityLabel, identity);
```